# Init a class with parameters that are only used by subclass

Tags: python, class, oop

Ok, so I'm not great with object-oriented stuff and I'm trying to figure out the "right" way to do this.

As a contrived example, class `Circle` is conceptually a subclass of `LogarithmicSpiral`, since circles are a special case of spirals, but because it's a more restricted type of thing, there's an opportunity to specify it in a different, more numerically accurate way:

```
mycircle = Circle(radius=, arc_length=, number_of_points=)
```

rather than

```
myspiral = LogarithmicSpiral(start_point=, step_vector=, number_of_points=)
```

To keep the subclass relationship, the guts of the initialization are still in `LogarithmicSpiral`, but it would then need to become something like `LogarithmicSpiral(start_point=None, step_vector=None, radius=None, arc_length=None, number_of_points=)`, with mutually exclusive parameters that can't be specified at the same time.  But then the `LogarithmicSpiral` class has extra parameters that aren't intended to be used with it directly.

What's the right way to go about something like this?  Make them both subclasses of some other object (but what geometrical shape would that be)?  Are there ways to have private initialization stuff that is only used by subclasses?

(This is for https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4607)

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that says a subclass has to accept the same arguments, or that a base class has to anticipate what arguments a subclass takes.

Your subclass has its own `__init__` methods, with their own arguments. You are free to re-use `LogarithmicSpiral.__init__`, or not, as you see fit. You could convert the arguments for `Circle` to arguments for the `LogarithmicSpiral.__init__` method:

```
class Circle(LogarithmicSpiral):
    def __init__(self, radius, arc_length, number_of_points):
        # calculate start_point and step_vector
        # ...
        LogarithmicSpiral.__init__(self, start_point, step_vector, number_of_points)
```

but if the rest of the class implementation doesn't need whatever attributes `LogarithmicSpiral.__init__` produces, then you are not obligated to.

If it helps the implementation, you are always free to delegate some of that work to a helper method, one starting with an initial `_` underscore. `LogarithmicSpiral.__init__()` would then call it, but so can `Circle.__init__()`:

```
class LogarithmicSpiral(Shape)
    def __init__(self, start_point, step_vector, number_of_points):
        # do some work, calculating some values like arg1, arg2, arg3
        self._setup_shape_params(arg1, arg2, arg3)

    def _setup_shape_params(arg1, arg2, arg3):
        # set up the instance attributes needed for a shape


class Circle(LogarithmicSpiral):
    def __init__(self, radius, arc_length, number_of_points):
        # do some work, calculating some values like arg1, arg2, arg3
        self._setup_shape_params(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Here `Circle.__init__()` doesn't call `LogarithmicSpiral.__init__()` directly, only the helper function.